# ASP.NET MVC forEach loop only returning 1 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am stuck with an issue.

I have a view that displays all my products like this:

```
    @foreach (var shoe in Model)
    {
        <div class="shoeCard card bg-dark col-1 me-3 mb-3">

                @if (shoe.Gender == "Male")
                {
                    <div class="shoeCardBg bg-primary z-1"></div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="shoeCardBg bg-danger z-1"></div>
                }
                <img src="@shoe.ImgUrl" class="card-img-top z-3" alt="@shoe.Name" style="position:relative;"  >
                <div class="card-body" id="card" onclick="Redirect()">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-light fw-bold">@shoe.Name</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-secondary lh-sm">@shoe.Gender</p>
                    <p class="card-text text-secondary lh-sm">@shoe.Brand</p>
                    <h4 class="card-text text-light lh-sm">£@shoe.Price</h4>
                </div>
                    <button id="AddToBasket" onclick="AddToBasket()" value="@shoe.ID" class="btn btn-light mb-2">Add to Basket</button>
        </div>
    }
```

Each button should have a value of a different ID but when I run this JS script only the value of `1` is returned.

```
<script>
    function Redirect() {
        var ID = $("#AddToBasket").val();
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Product", "Home")/' + ID;
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone know the issue? Thanks

Comment: Your loop is adding multiple IDs of #AddToBasket, which is invalid HTML - jQuery will only return the first value found in this case. Consider building an <a> href in the loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, adding multiple buttons with `id="AddToBasket` constitutes invalid HTML. When using `id` values, each element should be unique.

To get around this and simplify your code, I suggest you use `@Html.ActionLink` and make sure to style it to look like a button by applying a css style to it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
   "Add to Basket",
   "Product", // Your controller action
   "Home", // Your controller
   new { ID = shoe.ID },
   new { @class = "css-button-style" }
)
```

This code would replace your `<button....` code.

If you're using bootstrap, you can simply use `btn` for the `@class` value to style as a button. Otherwise, you might have to write some custom `css` to make sure that the button's styling is in line with the rest of your site.